# Await the same API call in multiple functions

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have an API call that I want to be called in one function, but awaited in a different callback.

E.g. I want to make a GET request on load so that the data is available as soon as possible, but I need a "submit" function to await the GET request so that it doesn't fire before the data is available.

This is due to a race condition I have between 2 asynchronous functions, where depending on API response time, could take more or less time than an authentication callback that has the control logic.

I'd rather perform both calls at the same time so that it can run as fast as possible in any scenario. I know this has higher cost since the data may not be used, but it's only done once per session on initial connection, so the potential decrease in load time is worth the extra potential extra API call.

That said, here's what I'm currently doing:

```
  let initialized = false;
  let dataError = null;
  let dataWaiters = [];
  const dataLoaded = () => new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
    if ( initialized ) resolve();
    if ( dataError ) reject( dataError );
    dataWaiters.push({ resolve, reject });
  });
```

This allows me to make my axios get request on load, which will then resolve any / all promises in `dataWaiters`.

```
async onStart () {
  // Attempt to use a local copy if we can
  if ( session.has.token.already ) {
    loadFromCache();
    return;
  }

  // Else we need to get data from API server
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://my-api-server/api/temp-token');
    saveResposne( data );
    this.initialized = true;
    dataWaiters.forEach( waiter => waiter.resolve() );
  } catch ( err ) {
    dataError = err;
    dataWaiters.forEach( waiter => waiter.reject(err) );
  }
}
```

Then in another callback function I can simply use `await dataLoaded()` to delay execution until this request had completed.

```
async onSomeCallback( data ) {
  if ( useTempToken ) {
    await dataLoaded();
    // use token...
  else {
    // use data...
  }
}
```

This works, but I feel like there should be a way I can use the `axios.get` promise in a better way, and maybe use fewer 'global' variables. Is there a way I can handle this more elegantly?

Comment: I'm a little confused ... where is the second asynchronous call? It looks like you only have one in the second code block.

Comment: Also, where does `saveResponse` come from? And `useTempToken`?

Comment: @djfdev `onStart` and `onSomeCallback` run in the same context. `onStart` at load / mount, and `onSomeCallback` runs after firebase has authenticated a user. If the user is not authenticated, I need to send a temporary `auth` to another server in order to access data. I don't want to wait for firebase to return before getting the temp auth though, and I can't run the `onSomeCallback` function without having either a temp auth *or* user auth.

Comment: What is `saveResponse`? And where is the Firebase logic? The example code seems incomplete. It would be helpful to see where the `onSomeCallback` function is actually called.

Comment: It is incomplete, I stripped out the logic that wasn't relevant because I'm only interested in a way to `await` a single promise (in this case a get request) in multiple places. The way the data is passed around and the related firebase functions aren't related and are just an example of the use case I have.

Comment: Right, I gathered that. I guess I'm questioning the pattern of "awaiting in multiple places" because it doesn't totally make sense to me.

Comment: Where does the Firebase auth get kicked off? Is that in the `onStart` function somewhere?

Comment: Use custom events OR a flag. `Promise.all([YOUR PROMISES]).then(() => ready=true)`

Comment: Here's an example of a maybe simpler user-case: https://github.com/AurityLab/vue-recaptcha-v3
You use `await this.$recaptchaLoaded()` to ensure the library has fully initialized before using the API. The alternative is to just use a callback when the library loads, but I wanted to explore the `await` option a little further since it's a cleaner syntax.

Comment: @Bibberty custom events seems like another reasonable approach that I haven't tried yet, but `Promise.all()` is kind of the opposite of what I want. Instead of waiting for multiple promises across a file, I want to await a single promise in multiple functions. The inverse of `promise.all` in a way.

Comment: @XanderLuciano Yes, if you want to `trigger` multiple actions once something is ready, then a custom event is the way to go. And infact I have used this for notifying core data is ready myself. (Custom Events)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events]

Comment: Here is a fairly simple demonstration of the concept. https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/CustomEventsToLinkScripts

Comment: If I have my logic correct, I would just check if the data was loaded, if it was loaded, just use it immediately, but if it was not loaded, register an event handler for *when* it loads. That does seem like a more appropriate pattern. Also, malformed your link, but I assume it was this page (or similar?) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of this working, very dumbed down. 
We declare a new Event. 
Then our data loader dispatches when ready.
We have an event listeners that trigger two actions.

```js
const data = [];

const dataReady = new CustomEvent('DataReady', {
  bubbles: true,
  detail: data
});

const populateData = () => {   
  setTimeout(() => {
    for(i = 0; i< 10; i++) data.push(i);
    console.log('test2');
    document.dispatchEvent(dataReady);
  }, 3000);
};

document.addEventListener('DataReady', ({ detail }) => {
  console.log(detail);
});

document.addEventListener('DataReady', ({ detail }) => {
  console.log(`Array length: ${detail.length}`);
});

populateData();
console.log('Test');
```

Comment: Looks logical enough to me. Thanks

Comment: No problem happy coding :)